# ¿Como puedo quitar los brackets, comillas simples y comas de la impresión de una lista de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, tkinter

tengo una duda acerca de como puedo quitar los brackets y las comillas simples de la impresión de texto de un label, los datos se imprimen de la siguiente manera :

La contraseña generada es: ['L', 'y', '.', 1, 3, 'q', 7, 'w', 's', 8, 2, 'v', 1, 'g']

Y yo quiero que se impriman asi:

La contraseña generada es: Ly.13q7ws82v1g

```
class Encriptacion:
    def __init__(self, numCaracteres):
        self.numCaracteres = numCaracteres
        self.datos = ["A",1, "B",2, "C",3, "D",4, "E",5, "F",7, "G",8, 
                      "H",9, "I",0, "J",1, "K",2, "L",3, "M",4, "N",5,
                      "O",6 ,"P",7, "Q",8, "R",9, "S",0,"T",1, "U",2, 
                      "V",3, "W",4, "X",5 ,"Y",6, "Z",7,
                      "a",7, "b",8, "c",9, "d",0 ,"e",1, "f",2, "g",3, 
                      "h",4 ,"i",5, "j",6, "k",7, "l",8,"m",9 ,"n",0,
                      "o",1, "p",2, "q",3, "r",4, "s",5,"t",1, "u",2, 
                      "v",3, "w",4, "x",5, "y",6, "z",7, '.',]

     # Generacion de datos
    def GenerarContraseña(self):
        numero = self.numCaracteres
        listadatos = []
        for x in range(1, numero):
            self.rand_dato = random.randint(1, 104)
            datosContraseña = self.datos[self.rand_dato]
            listadatos.append(datosContraseña)

        listadatos = str(listadatos)
        return listadatos
```

Espero puedan responder a mi duda:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que te hace falta es convertir todos los elementos de la lista en strings por que algunos son numeros (`listadatos.append(str(datosContraseña))`) y luego unirlos (`"".join(listadatos)`):

```
...
def GenerarContraseña(self):
    numero = self.numCaracteres
    listadatos = []
    for x in range(1, numero):
        self.rand_dato = random.randint(1, 104)
        datosContraseña = self.datos[self.rand_dato]
        listadatos.append(str(datosContraseña))

    return "".join(listadatos)
```

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la respuesta de Uriel, ya responde a tu pregunta, podrías evitar el incluir todos caracteres en `self.datos` con el modulo `string`:

```
class Encriptacion:
    def __init__(self, numCaracteres):
        self.numCaracteres = numCaracteres

     # Generacion de datos
    def GenerarContraseña(self):
        return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase +  # incluye 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                                      string.digits +  # incluye '0123456789'
                                      string.ascii_lowercase +  # incluye 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                      '.',  # incluye el punto
                                      k=self.numCaracteres))
```

Con esto ya obtendrías de forma aleatoria los caracteres entre `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.`

No sé si has repetido los numeros en tu codigo para que haya más probabilidades de que salgan, si es así y quisieras hacerlo también con este código, puedes multiplicar el numero de veces que aparecerán en las opciones:

```
string.digits *2  # esto entonces incluiría '01234567890123456789'
```

Te he puesto `string.ascii_lowercase` y `string.ascii_uppercase` para indicarte qué incluye cada uno, pero puedes cambiar ambos por `string.letters`. Mira la documentación para ver las posibilidades que tienes [Modulo String](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: No lo había visto de esa manera, mucho más eficiente y mejor, gracias por el aporte y checaré la documentación. :)

Answer (score 1):

Cambiar solo una línea

```
listadatos = ''.join(str(item) for item in listadatos)
```

Cada elemento de la lista se convierte primero en un string usando la función `str`, luego todo se combina en una línea usando el método de `join`.

Comment: Bienvenido, tu respuesta quedaría un poco mejor si explicas lo que hace cada cosa. Un saludo

Comment: @Capt.Teach, gracias, intentaré describir con más detalle.

Comment: Gracias a ti por el tiempo que inviertes en la comunidad